# Pass different argument on different times

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest, googlemock

I want to change different argument on different function call how to achieve this?

example:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*obj, Write(_)).WillOnce(DoAll(SaveArg<0>(&WriteObj), Return(true)));
```

The Write() method will be called multiple times or random times.
On each Write calls I want to get the object passed to Write() method. I want these arguments in a vector, how can I do this?

Comment: Has somebody passed a law prohibiting this `Write()` function from saving its argument in a vector, before doing its job?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik sorry I didn't get your point

Comment: Well, your question seems to suggest that, somehow, you are legally prohibited from doing exactly that: taking the argument to `Write`() and saving it in a vector.

Comment: Yes Write function will be called from multiple threads at random intervals

Comment: And I repeat: where is the law that prohibits one from saving the arguments into a vector? This is what mutexes are for: to implement thread-safe access to a shared object. Like for example, a vector where each parameter to each call to `Write`() gets saved. There's nothing you've written that makes that impossible, somehow.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik But that means changing the production code. What is the point of changing the tested method to save arguments it receives into a vector, if this vector is only used in unit tests?

Comment: If the "production code" is not written in a manner that facilitates convenient testing, then the answer is to rewrite production code in a manner that makes it convenient to test it. Make `Write()` a virtual method, and for testing define a subclass that overrides it, saves the argument in a vector, then invokes the parent class's real `Write()` method. That's just one way to do it, and it's not the only one. There are no hidden features of C++ that are known only to the privileged gurus. C++ works the same way for everyone, and its capabilities are well defined.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik What you say is true, code should be written in a manner that facilitates testing. However, it is not justified to do code refactoring in a case like this since you can use the testing framework to achieve desired result.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik as Mark said I don't believe to change the production code that is already tested. We can easily update the testing code and check whether the new module is working properly or not right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved my issue with this way.

in the test class

```
void SaveWritableObjects(WritableInterface * pWritableObject)
{
    WritableObjectList.push_back(pWritableObject);
}

std::vector<WritableInterface *> WritableObjectList;
```

And in the test function

```
 EXPECT_CALL(*pMFOI, Write(_)).WillRepeatedly(DoAll(Invoke(this, &intTestErrorEvents::SaveWritableObjects), Return(true)));
```

Comment: this is the correct way or any other simpler method is available with gtest/gmock